# How do I prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+2^nx^3}$ converges uniformly using the $M$-test?

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+2^nx^3}$ converges uniformly using the $M$-test? How can I find out such $M_n?$

Comment: You have been reminded before to show what you tried and where you are stuck. But again, see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 2):

The question has been edited.

You cannot prove this because the series is not uniformly convergent on the  real line. Note that $\frac 1 {1+2^{n}x^{3}} =\frac 1 2$ when $x=2^{-n/3}$. Hence $\frac 1 {1+2^{n}x^{3}} =\frac 1 2$ does  not tend to $0$ uniformly and the series is not uniformly convergent.

However the series converges uniformly in $\{x: |x| \geq \delta\}$ for any $\delta>0$. To prove this note that $|1+2^{n}x^{3}| \geq 2^{n} \delta ^{3}-1$ and verify that $\frac 1  {2^{n} \delta ^{3}-1} \leq \frac C {2^{n}}$ where $C=\frac 2 {\delta^{3}}$.

Comment: Sorry that I miss a condition, $x\in (1,\infty).$

Comment: I have a proved a more general result. In your case the series is dominated by $\frac 2 {2^{n}}$.

Comment: Why did you answer the question and voted to close it ?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Did you read the first sentence in my answer? The first version was meaningful but the question became one without context when the condition $x>1$ was added.  Subsequently the condition has been withdrawn.

Comment: I read the first sentence and checked the revision history, but it doesn't really help. If you decided that the question should be closed, you could have deleted your answer. It's not a big deal of course, just a bit surprising.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M_n=1/2^n$.  Then by comparison...

Answer (score 0):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} : $

Let $ x\geq 1 $, then $ \frac{1}{1+2^{n}x}\leq\frac{1}{1+2^{n}}\leq\frac{1}{2^{n}} \cdot $

Since $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 1}{\frac{1}{2^{n}}} $ converges, we get that $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 1}{\left(x\mapsto\frac{1}{1+2^{n}x}\right)} $ converges normally on $ \left(1,+\infty\right) \cdot $

Thus, it converges uniformly on $ \left(1,+\infty\right)\cdot $